# Weblogic Auto deploy changes xhtml using intellij idea

Tags: java, maven, jsf, intellij-idea, primefaces

I have a development project on ear project using `jsf` and `primafaces`. I'm using intellij 15.6 and web logic 12.1.1.0.

After I completed all the configuration on server and idea, I start server from idea, it makes and deploys the application but deploy fails.

After I do maven wls plugin undeploy, redeploy will is successfull. But when I change some xhtml files, I cannot see the changes in browser. Configuration server, update resources both them. I want to see the changes in xhtml after refresh browser or window.

Comment: I know Update Running Application option can be configured to just deploy resources for Tomcat, but it doesn't look like it can be for Weblogic. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html#specify

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you can't. When Weblogic loads your application it does so by staging your changes (in one way or another). Those staged files cannot be modified after loading. The best you can hope for is to leverage autodeploy, and after you build your application having a scripted deploy to the autodeploy directory. There is a possibility that if you had your project set up at the staging directory (and were not making any actual code changes) that you could tweak some files, as long as things are set up to not cache resources.

Here are the details you were looking for (note that you still need to re-compile):

- [Using FastSwap to speed up dev](http://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/using_fastswap_to_speed_up_dev)
- [Using FastSwap Deployment to Minimize Redeployment](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/DEPGD/deployunits.htm#DEPGD153)
- [Working with AutoDeploy](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/autodeploy.html#wp1021620)